# C++: Conditionals in template meta programming

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, template-meta-programming

I am implementing a program generating the next prime number from a given number `NUMBER` known at compile time with C++ template metaprogramming. However, I am currently stuck because I need a conditional value in my template. So I am searching for something like a ternary operator equivalent in C++.

My current approach:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef NUMBER
#define NUMBER 6
#endif

template <int P, int K = P - 1>
struct is_prime
{
    enum { value = P % K != 0 && is_prime<P, K - 1>::value }; 
};

template <int P>
struct is_prime<P, 1>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template<int P, bool B = is_prime<P>::value> 
struct next_prime
{
    // This doesn't work
    enum { value = ( B ? P : next_prime<P+1>::value )};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "next prime >= " << NUMBER << ": " << next_prime<NUMBER>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with `g++`, this results in an error:

```
In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<503, 4>’:
   recursively required from ‘struct is_prime<503, 501>’
   recursively required from ‘struct next_prime<3, true>’
   required from ‘struct next_prime<2>’
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 1000 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
```

Is there a good way to do this without using C++ 11?

Comment: Isn't the usual approach to this to use specialisation of `next_prime`?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings How would that look like? I tried declaring next_prime as above and then making a specialization struct next_prime<P, true> with value = P and a specialization struct next_prime<P, false> with value = next_prime<P+1, is_prime<P+1>::value>::value, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Should do. The key is to avoid instantiation of the unwanted case, otherwise it'll _always_ happen, and you'll get infinite instantiation, hence your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I see this sort of problem solved through specialization

```
template<int P, bool B = is_prime<P>::value> 
struct next_prime
 { enum { value = next_prime<P+1>::value }; };

template <int P> 
struct next_prime<P, true>
 { enum { value = P }; };
```

If you can use C++11 or newer, instead of defining a `value`, I suggest inheritance from `std::integral_constant`

```
// std::bool_constant<boolValue> is available starting from C++17;
// in C++11/C++14 you can use std::integral_constant<bool, boolValue>

template <int P, int K = P - 1>
struct is_prime
   : public std::bool_constant<P%K && (not is_prime<P, K-1>::value)>
 { };

template<int P>
struct is_prime<P, 2> : public std::bool_constant<P%2>
 { };

template<int K>
struct is_prime<2, K> : public std::true_type
 { };

template<int P, bool B = is_prime<P>::value> 
struct next_prime : public next_prime<P+1>
 { };

template <int P> 
struct next_prime<P, true> : public std::integral_constant<int, P>
 { };
```